# Is there a name for this convenience wrapper around std::future::then?

Tags: c++, future, naming

In the [jQuery version of "Deferreds"](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (what C++ calls "futures"), the `.then()` method takes as its argument a function whose signature doesn't contain any futures. Whereas, the `.then()` proposed for C++17 ([see N3721](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3721.pdf)) takes a function with `future` in its signature.

I.e., if I want to compute `f(g(x))` "in the background", N3721 wants me to write

```
extern int f(int);
extern int g(int);

auto async_fg(int x) {
    return std::async(f, x).then([](std::future<int> mid) {
        return g(mid.get());
    });
}
```

I'm tempted to write a wrapper, like this:

```
template<class F>
auto futurize(F&& f) {
    return [](auto mid) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(mid.get());
    };
}

auto async_fg(int x) {
    return std::async(f, x).then(futurize(g));
}
```

Both solutions seem awkward, though; and on top of it, I don't know the proper *name* for the operation I'm calling "futurize" here. If this operation has been proposed before, what have people called it?

---

Obviously an even better interface would be if `future<T>` had a new member function with the semantics

```
template<class T, class F>
auto future<T>::then_futurize(F&& f)
{
    return this->then(futurize(std::forward<F>(f)));
}

auto async_fg(int x) {
    return std::async(f, x).then_futurize(g);
}
```

Is there any (existing) name for *this* construct? (I just made up the name `then_futurize`, and I don't like it.)

---

I'll accept answers from any existing language or library (Javascript, Python, Ruby, C++ Boost, C++ Folly...); they don't have to be specifically C++ standards proposals, although obviously that would be best.

I've already noticed that [Folly's version of `.then()`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/futures/Future.h) takes a function with signature *either* `X(future<Y>)` *or* `X(Y)`; but I imagine that that would end up being ambiguous in some corner cases. Besides, the future-taking `.then()` and the "convenience wrapper" `.then()` seem like sufficiently different operations that I'd prefer different names for them.

Comment: I'd think about this in terms of monads mayhap.  But first I'd have to learn Haskell and monads.  I believe that .then is a kind of monad operation, and the unpack-and-call-.then is another haskell monad operation, maybe `>>=`?  Which has an english name, I think `bind`?  Which conflicts with `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! [N3865](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3865.pdf) has the same primitive that I called `.then_futurize()`; N3865 calls it `.next()`!

```
auto async_fg(int x) {
    return std::async(f, x).next(g);
}
```

N3865 also provides a counterpart `.recover()`, allowing Javascript-style continuation constructs:

```
std::future<std::string> f2 = f1.next(
    [](int v) {
        return v.to_string();
    }
).recover(
    [](exception_ptr ex) {
        return "nan";
    }
);
```

It also provides a bunch of other cool convenience wrappers, such as `.has_value()` and `.value_or()`.

(I don't see any name for my `futurize()`, but `.then_futurize()` is definitely named `.next()`.)

Comment: I was about to ask the question what the difference between `next` and `then` is. Hard to lookup online... You explained that comparing the code examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about `do_next`?

```
template<class F>
auto do_next( F&& f )
{
  return [f = std::forward<F>(f)]( auto&& fut ) {
    return f( decltype(fut)(fut).get() );
  };
}

auto async_fg(int x) {
  return std::async(f, x).then(do_next(g));
}
```

as noted above, treating future as a Haskell monad, then I think `then(do_next` is `>>=` aka `bind`, but that isn't practical.

You could also take a page from named operators:

```
namespace named_operator {
  template<class D>struct make_operator{make_operator(){}};

  template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; };

  template<class Lhs, class Op>
  half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op> operator*( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op> ) {
      return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
  }

  template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
  auto operator*( half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
  -> decltype( invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) )
  {
      return invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
}

namespace my_operator {
  struct do_next_t{};
  static const named_operator<do_next_t> do_next;

  template<class T, class F,
    class R = std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F>(T)>
  >
  auto invoke( std::future<T>&& lhs, do_next_t, F&& f )
  -> std::future< R >
  {
    return lhs.then( [f = std::forward<F>(f)](std::future<T> fut)mutable->R {
      return std::move(f)(std::forward<F>(fut.get()));
    });
  };
}
using my_operator::do_next;
```

which gives you:

```
auto async_fg(int x) {
  return std::async(f, x) *do_next* g;
}
```

or some other name like `*then_do*`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682f917c7dcb3c47) (fails on call to .then).

...

Decoding Haskell, I think `.then` is `fmap` on functors, `.then(futurize` is `>>=` or `bind` on monads, which means `futurize` is `lift` on functors.

`>>=` or `bind` is generally considered easier to use than `fmap`/`lift`; composing the two is often done, into one concept.

Comment: That metaprogramming implementation is clever, but irrelevant. ;)  The suggestion of `do_next` makes as much sense as `futurize`... but does it have any prior art behind it? Is there anyone out in the world right now calling this thing `do_next`? I'm looking specifically for prior art. (I will try to read up on Haskell and `>>=` / `bind`, although my own Haskell skill is zero and you've already pointed out the possible confusion with `std::bind` there.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone aha!  `futurize` is a Haskell `lift` on the functor of `future` -- `then` is `fmap` methinks!